# Verification of simple proof of coercivity

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

I just want to check the following simple proof:

Consider the operator $A: X \rightarrow X^{*}$. Then A is called coercive if and only if $$\lim\limits_{\Vert u \Vert_{X} \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\langle Au,u \rangle_{X}}{\Vert u \Vert_{X}} = + \infty$$

I want to show that there exists a number $R_{0} > 0$ such that $\langle Au,u  \rangle > c$, for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and for all $u \in X: \Vert u \Vert_{X} \geq R_{o}$.

Proof:
Assume this is not true. Take some arbitrary $c \in \mathbb{R}$. It follows then that there exists a $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m \geq n$ and $\langle Au_{m}, u_{m} \rangle \leq c$. Then $\frac{\langle Au_{m}, u_{m} \rangle_{X}}{\Vert u_{m} \Vert_{X}} \leq \frac{c}{\Vert u_{m} \Vert_{X}}$, then passing to the limit as $m \rightarrow \infty$ we have then cannot have $\lim\limits_{m \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\langle Au_{m}, u_{m} \rangle}{\Vert u_{m} \Vert_{X}} \rightarrow  \infty$. This contradicts the assumed coercivity.

Is this proof fine?

Answer (score 0):

> there exists a $m\in \mathbb N$ such that $m\ge n $

You are referring to something called "$n$", which wasn't previously defined.

I think the situation is more clear without an argument by contradiction. Begin with what you know: for every $c$ there is $R$ such that 
$$ \frac{\langle Au,u \rangle_{X}}{\Vert u \Vert_{X}} > c\quad \text{whenever}\quad \|u\|_X \ge R$$
The above implies (why?) that 
$$ \frac{\langle Au,u \rangle_{X}}{\Vert u \Vert_{X}} > c\quad \text{whenever}\quad \|u\|_X \ge \max(R,1)$$
which in turn implies (why?) 
$$  \langle Au,u \rangle_{X}  > c\quad \text{whenever}\quad \|u\|_X \ge \max(R,1)$$

Comment: Does the first part '$\frac{\langle Au,u \rangle}{\Vert u \Vert_{X}} > c$ whenever $\Vert u \Vert_{X} \geq R$'  follow simply from the definition of the limit of a function $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x) = +\infty$? We therefore have nothing to prove?

Comment: @JohnDoe Yes, it's a very simple thing. Has nothing to do with operators, really. Compare to: if $f(x)/|x|\to \infty$ as $x\to\infty$, then $f(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.